# cmfcpropertygridctrl in dialog can't be edited

Tags: c++, mfc

I create a dialog derived from CDialogEx, then add a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl on it, generate a control value of m_wndPropList binding to the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, in OnInitDialog, I add the initial code:

```
BOOL CPropDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    InitPropList(); // here I add the initial function
    return TRUE; 
}
```

the codes in InitPropList() are just copy from the example code, generated by VS2015 when creating a MFC project with visual studio style.

when I have done all the work, the property ctrl display well, but it can't be edited, and doesn't respons to the mouse. please kindly help me, thanks!

Comment: Did you try to call `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::PreTranslateMessage` in dialog PreTranslateMessage method ?